# Representing a computational graph in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, automatic-differentiation

I'm trying to write a simple automatic differentiation package in Haskell.

What are the efficient ways to represent a type-safe (directed) computational graph in Haskell? I know that the [ad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) package uses the "data-reify" method for that but I'm not quite familiar with it. Can anyone provide me with some insights? Thanks!

Comment: see http://conal.net/papers/compiling-to-categories/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Will Ness' comment indicates, the correct abstraction for AD is a category, not a graph. Unfortunately the standard [`Category` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html#t:Category) doesn't really do the trick, because it requires arrows between *any* Haskell types, but differentiation only makes sense between *smooth manifolds*. Most libraries don't know about manifolds and restrict it further to Euclidean vector spaces (which they represent as “vectors” or “tensors” which are just arrays). There really isn't a compelling reason to be *that* restrictive – any [affine space](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-AffineSpace.html) will do for forward-mode AD; for reverse mode you also need a notion of the dual space to difference vectors.

```
data FwAD x y = FwAD (x -> (y, Diff x -> Diff y))
data RvAD x y = RvAD (x -> (y, DualVector (Diff y) -> DualVector (Diff x)))
```

where the `Diff x -> Diff y` function must be a [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function). (You can use [a dedicated arrow type for such functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.4.0.1/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html#t:LinearFunction), or you can just use `(->)` functions which happen to be linear.) The only thing that's different in reverse-mode is that the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of this linear map is represented, instead of the map itself. (In a real-valued matrix implementation, the linear mapping is the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) and the adjoint version its transpose, but *don't* use matrices, they're terribly inefficient for this.)

Neat, right? All that graph/traversal/mutation/backwards-pass nonsense that people keep talking about isn't really needed. (See [Conal's paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3236765) for elaboration.)

So, to make this useful in Haskell you need to implement the category combinators. This is pretty much exactly what I wrote the [constrained-categories package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories) for. Here's an outline instantiation for what you need:

```
import qualified Prelude as Hask
import Control.Category.Constrained.Prelude
import Control.Arrow.Constrained
import Data.AffineSpace
import Data.AdditiveGroup
import Data.VectorSpace

instance Category FwAD where
  type Object FwAD a
     = (AffineSpace a, VectorSpace (Diff a), Scalar (Diff a) ~ Double)
  id = FwAD $ \x -> (x, id)
  FwAD f . FwAD g = FwAD $ \x -> case g x of
     (gx, dg) -> case f gx of
       (fgx, df) -> (fgx, df . dg)

instance Cartesian FwAD where
  ...
instance Morphism FwAD where
  ...
instance PreArrow FwAD where
  ...
instance WellPointed FwAD where
  ...
```

The instances are all easy and almost unambiguous, let the compiler messages guide you (*typed holes* `_` are enormously useful). Basically, whenever a variable of a type that's in scope is required, use it; when a variable of vector-space type that's *not* in scope is required, use [`zeroV`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-AdditiveGroup.html#v:zeroV).

At that point you'll really have all the fundamental *differentiable functions* tooling in place, but to actually define such functions you would need to use point-free style with lots of `.`, `&&&` and `***` combinators and hard-coded numerical primitives, which looks unconventional and rather confusing. To avoid that, you can use [agent values](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:HasAgent): values that basically pretend to be simple number variables, but actually contain an entire category arrow from some fixed domain type. (This would basically be the “building up a graph” part of the exercise.) You can simply use the provided [`GenericAgent`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:GenericAgent) wrapper.

```
instance HasAgent FwAD where
  type AgentVal FwAD a v = GenericAgent FwAD a v
  alg = genericAlg
  ($~) = genericAgentMap

instance CartesianAgent FwAD where
  alg1to2 = genericAlg1to2
  alg2to1 = genericAlg2to1
  alg2to2 = genericAlg2to2

instance PointAgent (GenericAgent FwAD) FwAD a x where
  point = genericPoint

instance ( Num v, AffineSpace v, Diff v ~ v, VectorSpace v, Scalar v ~ v
         , Scalar a ~ v )
      => Num (GenericAgent FwAD a v) where
  fromInteger = point . fromInteger
  (+) = genericAgentCombine . FwAD $ \(x,y) -> (x+y, \(dx,dy) -> dx+dy)
  (*) = genericAgentCombine . FwAD $ \(x,y) -> (x*y, \(dx,dy) -> y*dx+x*dy)
  abs = genericAgentMap . FwAD $ \x -> (abs x, \dx -> if x<0 then -dx else dx)
  ...
instance ( Fractional v, AffineSpace v, Diff v ~ v, VectorSpace v, Scalar v ~ v
         , Scalar a ~ v )
      => Fractional (GenericAgent FwAD a v) where
  ...
instance (...) => Floating (...) where
  ...
```

If you have all those instances complete, and perhaps a simple helper to extract the results

```
evalWithGrad :: FwAD Double Double -> Double -> (Double, Double)
evalWithGrad (FwAD f) x = case f x of
   (fx, df) -> (fx, df 1)
```

then you can write code such as

```
> evalWithGrad (alg (\x -> x^2 + x) 3)
(12.0, 7.0)
> evalWithGrad (alg sin 0)
(0.0, 1.0)
```

Under the hood, these algebraic expressions build up a composition of `FwAD` arrows with [`&&&`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#v:-38--38--38-) “splitting” the data flow and [`***`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#v:-42--42--42-) composing in parallel, i.e. even if the input and final result are simple `Double` then the intermediate results will be pulled through a suitable tuple type. [That would, I guess, be the answer to your title question: the directed graph is in a sense represented as a branched composition chain, in principle the same thing as you find in those [diagram explanations of `Arrow`s](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows).]

Comment: is this idea of `Agent`s your own, or could I read more about it in the literature, under perhaps a different name?

Comment: It is strongly inspired by the Conal Elliott's earlier work, which is summarized in the [compiling to categories](https://doi.org/10.1145/3110271) paper. Basically, the idea is wanting to write those CCC expressions as lambdas, but only using existing Haskell tools. I think it is also closely related to Yoneda / Coyoneda mechanisms, but I could never quite figure out how...